# Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit samba failed to install

Tags: 13.10

Ubuntu software centre indicates samba installed but Unity search indicates samba not found. Terminal returns samba not installed. How can I enable samba?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba - use `apt-get` to install it, see if that works.

Comment: Thanks wilf. I used apt-get and can access Samba Server Configuration in terminal. Any advice on how to get Dash to find Samba and show an icon button on the Launcher?

Comment: I managed to get an icon button on the Launcher by running gksudo system-config-samba.

Comment: Weird, I get similar results. What is needed is a .desktop launcher. What happens when you run `ls -l /usr/share/applications/system-config-samba.desktop`? If that returns an error, try `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep samba`. If that also fails, I shall add instructions for creating a launcher in a bit.

Comment: Thanks wilf your answer was helpful. I pasted the short version into nano and after reboot Dash search found samba and displayed the samba icon on Launcher. So all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a samba launcher file, first run this in terminal - nano is a easy-to-use command-line text editor:

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/system-config-samba2.desktop`

Then copy one of the texts below *(sourced from launcher file on my Fedora computer, **but works on my Ubuntu system**)*, and paste this into `nano` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> probably).

**Short version:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Samba
Comment=Create, modify, and delete samba shares
Icon=system-config-samba
Exec=gksudo /usr/bin/system-config-samba
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.21
```

**Long version, based on original:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Samba
Name[ar]=سامبا
Name[as]=Samba
Name[ast]=Samba
Name[bg]=Samba
Name[bn]=Samba
Name[bn_IN]=Samba
Name[bs]=Samba
Name[ca]=Samba
Name[cs]=Samba
Name[cy]=Samba
Name[da]=Samba
Name[de]=Samba
Name[de_CH]=Samba
Name[el]=Samba
Name[en_GB]=Samba
Name[es]=Samba
Name[et]=Samba
Name[eu]=Samba
Name[fa]=سامبا
Name[fi]=Samba
Name[fr]=Samba
Name[gu]=સામ્બા
Name[he]=Samba
Name[hi]=सांबा
Name[hr]=Samba
Name[hu]=Samba
Name[id]=Samba
Name[is]=Samba
Name[it]=Samba
Name[ja]=Samba
Name[kn]=Samba
Name[ko]=Samba
Name[lv]=Samba
Name[mai]=सांबा
Name[mk]=Самба
Name[ml]=സാംബാ
Name[mr]=Samba
Name[ms]=Samba
Name[nb]=Samba
Name[nds]=Samba
Name[nl]=Samba
Name[or]=ଶାମ୍ବା
Name[pa]=ਸਾਂਬਾ
Name[pl]=Samba
Name[pt]=Samba
Name[pt_BR]=Samba
Name[ro]=Samba
Name[ru]=Samba
Name[si]=සම්බා
Name[sk]=Samba
Name[sl]=Samba
Name[sr]=Самба
Name[sr@latin]=Samba
Name[sv]=Samba
Name[ta]=சம்பா
Name[te]=సాంబ
Name[th]=Samba
Name[tr]=Samba
Name[uk]=Samba
Name[vi]=Samba
Name[zh_CN]=Samba
Name[zh_TW]=Samba
Comment=Create, modify, and delete samba shares
Comment[ar]=إنشاء، تعدّيل وحذف مجلدات سامبا المُشتركة
Comment[as]=samba অংশৰ সৃষ্টি, সাল-সলনি কৰক বা আঁতঁতৰা দিয়কই 
Comment[ast]=Criar, camudar y desaniciar recursos compartíos samba
Comment[bg]=Създаване, редактиране и премахване на samba споделени ресурси
Comment[bn]=Samba শেয়ার নির্মাণ, পরিবর্তন এবং অপসারণ পদ্ধতি
Comment[bn_IN]=Samba শেয়ার নির্মাণ, পরিবর্তন এবং অপসারণ পদ্ধতি
Comment[bs]=Izrada, izmjena ili brisanje Samba dijeljenih mapa
Comment[ca]=Creeu, modifiqueu i elimineu recursos compartits samba
Comment[cs]=Přidat, upravit nebo smazat sdílené adresáře
Comment[cy]=Creu, addasu, a dileu rhaniadau samba
Comment[da]=Opret, ændr og fjern samba-delinger
Comment[de]=Samba-Freigaben anlegen, ändern und löschen
Comment[de_CH]=Samba-Freigaben anlegen, ändern und löschen
Comment[el]=Δημιουργία,  μετατροπή,  και διαγραφή κοινών πόρων samba
Comment[en_GB]=Create, modify, and delete samba shares
Comment[es]=Crear, modificar y borrar recursos compartidos samba
Comment[et]=Loo, muuda ja kustuta samba jagamisi
Comment[fa]=ایجاد , تغییر , و حذف  اشتراکهای سامبا 
Comment[fi]=Luo, muokkaa ja poista samba-jakoja
Comment[fr]=Créer, modifier et supprimer les partages Samba
Comment[gu]=સામ્બા શેરો બનાવો, સુધારો અને કાઢી નાંખો
Comment[he]=יצירה, שינוי, ומחיקת שיתופי Samba
Comment[hi]=सांबा साझा बनाएँ, संशोधित, और विलोपित करें
Comment[hr]=Izrada, izmjena ili brisanje Samba dijeljenih mapa
Comment[hu]=Samba megosztások létrehozása, módosítása és törlése
Comment[id]=Buat, modifikasi, dan hapus samba shares
Comment[is]=Búa til, breyta eða eyða samba sameignum
Comment[it]=Crea, modifica e rimuove condivisioni samba
Comment[ja]=Samba 共有の作成、変更および削除
Comment[kn]=Samba ಹಂಚಿಕೆಗಳನ್ನು ಸೃಷ್ಟಿಸು, ಬದಲಾಯಿಸು ಹಾಗು ಅಳಿಸು
Comment[ko]=samba 공유를 생성, 수정하고 삭제하기
Comment[lv]=Izveidot, modificēt un dzēst Samba koplietojumus
Comment[mai]=सांबा साझा बनाउ, संशोधित, आओर विलोपित  करू 
Comment[mk]=Креирај, уреди и отстрани самба делења
Comment[ml]=സാംബാ ഷെയറുകള്‍ ഉണ്ടാക്കുവാനും മാറ്റം വരുത്തുവാനും നീക്കം ചെയ്യുവാനും സഹായിക്കുന്നു
Comment[mr]=samba शेअर निर्माण, बदल, आणि नष्ट करा
Comment[ms]=Cipta, ubahsuai, dan padam pengkongsian samba
Comment[nb]=Opprett, endre og slett samba-ressurser
Comment[nl]=Aanmaken, wijzigen en verwijderen van Samba gedeelde bronnen
Comment[or]=ଶାମ୍ବା ର ସହଭାଗ ମାନଙ୍କୁ ସ୍ରୁଷ୍ଟି କର, ରୂପାନ୍ତର କର, ଏବଂ ଅପସାରଣ କର
Comment[pa]=ਸਾਂਬਾ ਸ਼ੇਅਰ ਬਣਾਓ, ਸੋਧੋ ਅਤੇ ਹਟਾਓ
Comment[pl]=Tworzenie, modyfikacja i usuwanie udziałów Samby
Comment[pt]=Criar, modificar e apagar partilhas samba
Comment[pt_BR]=Crie, modifique e apague compartilhamentos do Samba
Comment[ro]=Creează, modifică şi şterge partajări samba
Comment[ru]=Создание, изменение и удаление ресурсов Samba
Comment[si]=සම්බා හවුල් සාදන්න, සංශෝධනය කරන්න නැතහොත් මකාදමන්න
Comment[sk]=Vytvoriť, upraviť alebo odstrániť samba zdieľania
Comment[sl]=Izdela, spremeni in izbriše skupne diske SMB
Comment[sr]=Направи, измени, и обриши Самба дељене ресурсе
Comment[sr@latin]=Napravi, izmeni, i obriši Samba deljene resurse
Comment[sv]=Skapa, ändra och ta bort sambautdelningar
Comment[ta]=சம்பா பகிர்வுகளை உருவாக்கவும், திருத்தவும், அழிக்கவும்
Comment[te]=సాంబా భాగాలను సృష్టించు, మార్చు, మరియూ తొలగించు
Comment[th]=สร้าง, แก้ไขและลบการแบ่งปันทาง Samba
Comment[tr]=Samba paylaşımlarını oluşturur, değiştirir ve siler
Comment[uk]=Створення, зміна чи видалення ресурсів Samba
Comment[vi]=Tạo, hiệu chỉnh, và xóa Chia sẻ Samba
Comment[zh_CN]=创建、修改和删除 samba 共享
Comment[zh_TW]=建立、修改與刪除 Samba 共享
Categories=System;Settings;
Icon=system-config-samba
Exec=gksudo /usr/bin/system-config-samba
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.21
```

Note the `Exec=` line and the `Terminal=true` line. The first is what command will be executed, while the second means that it will be launched in the terminal. **This bit has to be in the launcher file so that the sudo password can be typed in**, but if it does it automatically or does not require the password, you can set this to `Terminal=false`.

Now you can save it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, and exit by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Now you should be able to find it in the dash, but you may need to logout and login, or reboot to see any changes.

If the launcher shows, but you want to change the icon, just change `Icon=system-config-samba` to `Icon=/usr/share/icons/PATH/TO/REQUIRED/IMAGE`

The icon may look like one of these:
[image: icon 1]   [image: icon 2]  [image: icon 3]

Hope you find atleast some of this fairly bizarre answer helpful [image: smiley]